# Does @_jscript no longer represent true in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jscript

```
<script>
/*@cc_on
   @if (@_jscript)
      alert("IE.");
   @else*/
      alert("Not IE.");
   /*@end
@*/
</script>
```

When I ran the code above, Firefox and IE all showed a popup dialog that tell me "Not IE.".
Why did this happend. Is *@_jscript* no longer defined in IE 11?

IE version: 11.0.9600.17501

Comment: Yes IE is starting to support W3C standards, including dropping support for non standard browser sniffing.

Comment: Sorry. My English is not very good. So I didn't know the "conditional compilation" term and didn't search that question out.

Answer (score 0):

> Did @_jscript no longer defined in IE 11?

No.

Few features in earlier versions of IE Is not Supported for IE10+ . It's Removed.

Instead of Using `@_jscript` You can try the following Code

```
 function msieversion()
{
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent
  var msie = ua.indexOf ( "MSIE " )

  if ( msie > 0 )      // If Internet Explorer, return version number
     return parseInt (ua.substring (msie+5, ua.indexOf (".", msie )))
  else                 // If another browser, return 0
     return 0

}
```

[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167820)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for help on referencing things not written by you. As your answer is currently written, it sounds as though you were speaking on behalf of the IE team.

Comment: Thank you very much. IE make web programming a little hard I think...

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with HTML5 parsing.